# How to configure my react project for prioritize files ending in `.web.*` to be included in my bundle?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parcel, plasmo

I am trying to use a react-native based library called `react-native-reanimated`. This library has some components that are also supported for the web, and they write 2 files, for example a `measure` component will have `measure.tsx` and `measure.web.tsx` file. When I use this library in a nextJS project, it bundles the correct file for web, which is `measure.web.tsx`, however with plasmo, it seems like it only bundles the files with extensions `.ts` or `.js` etc..., and skips the equivalent `.web.*` file.

How do I make parcel make the files that end in `.web.*` take precendence over `.js|ts(x)` files?

---

- This one has code specific for react-native, and doesn't work on the web but the web file is not bundled
  [image: File without .web extension]
- In the nextJS app you can see that it bundles the .web.js file

[image: File with .web.js extension bundled]